# Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server 2022 can't connect

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2022

I have a trivial console app and I can't connect my `DBContext` (Entity Framework 6.0.0) to the SQL Server 2022 database.

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(string connectionString) :base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);       
    }
}
```

Connecting with `SqlConnection` works just fine, but EF6 doesn't. There's no error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    cb.DataSource = @"***";
    cb.InitialCatalog = @"EF6Test";
    cb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = cb.ConnectionString;
    conn.Open(); //connection OK.

    try
    {
        using (var ctx = new TestContext(cb.ConnectionString))
        {
            var s = ctx.Database.Connection.State;
            ;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I add a breakpoint, the only error is here:

[image]

**Edit**: this is my `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="v11.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try adding this line before connecting: `cb.TrustServerCertificate = true;`

Comment: @marc_s Still same problem. SqlConnection works, DbContext doesn't. I have no clue what is going on.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Also, the exception should have an inner exception that tells what's wrong.